# Solving $x y'(x) = \tan y(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I got this differential equation, but I don't know how to find its solution.

$$
xy'(x) = \tan y(x)
$$

Can anyone provide me with a hint?

Answer (score 4):

It's separable $$\cot y \,dy = \dfrac{dx}{x}$$

So $$\begin{align} \int \dfrac{\cos y}{\sin y}\,dy & = \int \dfrac{dx}{x} \\ \\ &\iff \ln|\sin y| = \ln|x| + C\end{align}$$

Take the exponential of each side to get $\;\sin y = cx $.

Answer (score 0):

$$\ xy'(x)=\tan y(x) \implies x\frac{dy}{dx}=\tan y\implies \frac{dy}{\tan y}=\frac{dx}{x}$$
Now integrating you get
$$\ \int\frac{dy}{\tan y}=\int \frac{dx}{x}\implies \int \frac{\cos y}{\sin y}dy=\int \frac{dx}{x}$$
$$\ \implies\log|\sin y|=\log|x|+C$$